# cakephp takes me to login page on multiple request

Tags: cakephp

On my cakephp based site, when i do multiple requests simultaneously, cakephp logs me out.

What happens exactly is,

I click on one of the link on my site,  to open it in a new tab, 
now, while the request is being processed, if i click another link on my site, cakephp takes me to the login page for this link...
What can be the solution for this?

Thanks...

Comment: Is there any logic in your code that might log you out? I also would check the cake installation. This seems to be completely out of Cake's logic to happen.

Comment: ok, a little change in what i said before, when i click on 2nd link, while the first is pprocessing, the 2nd click link takes me to the login page ( but it doesnt logs me out)

Comment: so you are still logged in even after you have been taken to the login page right? sounds simply like a bug in your code. follow the code that does this process, comment out lines, use debug. That's how you fix these stuff.

Comment: Thanks guys, but the prob is solved.....with the answer below....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet this is your problem:

```
 * CakePHP session IDs are also regenerated between requests if
 * 'Security.level' is set to 'high'.
 */
    Configure::write('Security.level', 'high');
```

You're running into problems with Cake regenerating the cookie for two requests simultaneously.