# CakePHP + HTML5 Prefething = Logging Out

Tags: firefox, cakephp, html, logout, prefetch

After adding HTML5 Prefetch links to head section of default.ctp, all firefox users (in CakePHP application im working on) are keep getting logged out after next page refresh.
Any ideas how to make CakePHP prefetch-friendly?

Here is example prefetch links placed inside head of the page:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/" />
<link rel="prefetch" href="/users/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103453/cakephp-takes-me-to-login-page-on-multiple-request/3106710#3106710) could be your problem.

Comment: This is not a source of my problem.
I already have 'low' setting.