# CakePHP Session keeps getting reset

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm setting a Session variable with an ajax call. I've tried both by using the helper and by using the straight PHP $_SESSION syntax. For some reason, whenever I reload the page, all SESSION data is gone.

What is annoying about this, is that it happens sporadically. I thought at first, it had to do with the browser I was using, but it does not. I have tried changing all the Session settings in core.php and no combination seems to be reliable.

Any thoughts as to how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Possibly related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103453/cakephp-takes-me-to-login-page-on-multiple-request/3106710#3106710

Comment: I wish. That doesn't seem to have an effect..

Comment: Try to keep close track of all cookies on both sides then. Look at the information sent by and returned to the browser using Firebug or Fiddler, and possibly log the active `session_id()` on the server. This may help you find when the problem is occurring.

Comment: I should add that I'm using mod_rewrite since all my files are in another directory (on the same server). Could I accidentally be creating a session that is not accessible by the entire application?

Comment: OK, I've noticed the problem. Everything works when there is a www. in front of my domain. However, all my links automatically drop the "www". Is there anyway I can have cake automatically include the "www" ?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. But there are different sessions going on whether or not there is a www.

Comment: You should make an .htaccess rewrite rule to use one canonical domain name (either www. or no www.), and redirect all other requests to the canonical form. It's better for SEO and avoids problems like this. Try to learn about cookie validity across subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to open the `app/config/core.php` file and modify the `Security.level` section. From the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/42/The-Configuration-Class):

> **Security.level**
>
> The level of CakePHP security. The
>   session timeout time defined in
>   'Session.timeout' is multiplied
>   according to the settings here.
>
> Valid values: 'high' = x 10 'medium' =
>   x 100 'low' = x 300
>
> 'high' and 'medium' also enable
>   [session.referer_check](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.referer-check)
>
> CakePHP session IDs are also
>   regenerated between requests if
>   'Security.level' is set to 'high'.

Search the `core.php` file for `Security.level` and change the setting to `low` and ensure you `Session.timeout` value is high enough. You may have to play with both of these settings until your satisfied.

Comment: Yeah, I've done all these things. What seems to get the session working is when i use a combination of session_destroy(); and unset($_SESSION); Once I do this once and reload, my session starts working... However, this is less than ideal