# how to get $_SESSION value in cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am setting up a user session from a core php app that is located in **example.com/corephp/**, now I want to redirect this user to **example.com** (the main site) which is in cakephp.

How can I retain the user session from the core php app to cakephp app?

I triend setting `$_SESSION['user'] = someone` and `$_SESSION['token'] = token` from core php app and tried to retrieve that value from cakephp but it didn't work.

I tried to google for this but no proper answer that could work.

Thanks in advance.

---------------------- edit

I have tried adding session_name('CAKEPHP');  to the core php app.
As well as tried to reduce the security level of my cake app from medium to low.

Comment: did you try `print_r($this->Session->read());` ?

Comment: yes, I see config array with userAgent, time and timeout values

Comment: thanks for your efforts guys, so the theory say that if set $_SESSION in core php app and they are on the same server, I should get it in cake as it is from $_SESSION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't test, but try this.

In your corephp app:

```
$_SESSION['Auth']['User'] = $someone;
```

My reasoning is that it will set the $_SESSION, but maybe CakePHP doesn't recognize it for some reason. So we set it the right way using Cake's API:

In CakePHP

```
$this->Session->write('Auth.User', $_SESSION['Auth']['User']);
```

Comment: I get $_SESSION['user'] as null in your example

Comment: @happyhardik: $_SESSION['user'] is null in CakePHP?

Comment: yes, I am setting the variable as $_SESSION['username'] (to be exact) from core php app and it is undefined in my cake app

Comment: Are the two systems using the same session name? I.e. do they use the same session cookie (same session ID)?

Comment: I tried doing something like this session_name('CAKEPHP');  in my core php app but it didn't help

Comment: Updated the answer. Maybe it helps. Additionally, here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877341/cakephp-session-keeps-getting-reset

Comment: Finally I figured it out, the request that my core php app received was through ajax and through a proxy server (for cross domain) which changed the session for user and proxy server :)

Answer (score 0):

Always use the session wrappers. thats what they are there for

in the controller:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#using-components

in the view:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html

everywhere else:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#reading-writing-session-data

never ever access it using $_SESSION and you should be fine (cake inits the session for you and takes care of a lot of things behind the hood).

if you share the session make sure you set the session name equally. both should also use the same session type (php probably).